# Counting rows upwards from designated cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly weak at VBA. 
I am trying to find the rows count of table 1 and table 2 in the pic.

[image: Trying to find no. of rows count in table 1 and 2]

I tried to count the rows upwards(working backwards) from Cell `A12` in the following VBA code,

```
LastRow=sheet("Sheet1").Range("A12").end(xlUp).row
```

But it doesn't seem to work. 
`Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` will count rows up to `table2`; hence doesn't work. 

Do you have a better idea/code to count Table 1 and Table 2? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with `Range.Areas` after you use `SpecialCells`. Something along these lines:

```
Sub Test()

Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Get a full range of where your tables sit.
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Loop through all different tables
    For Each Area In rng.Areas
        Debug.Print Area.Cells(1, 1).Value & " has " & Area.Rows.Count - 1 & " rows of data."
    Next Area

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FFF()
    Dim rng, cell
    Set cell = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) '//Start cell
    Do
        Set rng = cell.CurrentRegion
        MsgBox "The count of cells in table " & rng.Address & " is: " & rng.Cells.Count
        Set cell = rng(1).End(xlUp)
    Loop Until cell.Row = 1
End Sub
```